# Captioning an mdframed box without making unbreakable

Tags: listings, captions, page-breaking, mdframed

I would like to a have a caption below my `mdframed` box (outside the border if possible) which sometimes span across multiple pages. I managed to create a caption several ways but the pagebreaks are unfriendly. How can I do that without making the box unbreakable at pagebreaks?

The `listings` package is not an alternative, because I already use it inside somewhere in the mdframed box, and nesting them doesn't seem like a good idea.

Associated thread: [use this inside `\lstnewenvironment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135737/using-listings-inside-mdframed-causes-unknown-compilation-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might be what the after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum,mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,mdframed}
\newmdenv[linecolor=red,frametitle=Infobox]{infoboxmd}
\makeatletter
\def\@noargument{noargument}
\newenvironment{infobox}[1][noargument]
  {\gdef\@opt@arg{#1}% Caption optional argument
   \infoboxmd}
  {\endinfoboxmd\par\nobreak%
   \ifx\@opt@arg\@noargument\else\centering\@opt@arg\par\fi}%
\begin{document}

\begin{infobox}[This is a caption]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{infobox}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm rather curious about why you always change the test for no optional argument. `;-)` The `\gdef` can be, more simply, `\def`.

Comment: @egreg: I don't know. Testing it with `\relax` would be simpler. You're right, it could be `\def`.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the quick reply. To be honest, I don't fully understand the underlying logic, so if you can point in a direction to gain that knowledge, I will follow. One more thing: is there a way to keep at least one line with the caption? It's pretty bad-looking alone. (I should have asked this - I'll edit the question.)

Comment: @Werner: UPDATE2: I tried to use it in `\lstnewenvironment` with less luck. (It works with `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`, but it's useless that way, because the lst environment has the caption text.) :(

Comment: One could exploit `aftersingleframe` and `afterlastframe`

Comment: I've decided to remove the updates and ask them as new questions based on your solution. I can finally accept your solution this way.