# Using listings inside mdframed causes unknown compilation error

Tags: errors, listings, mdframed

I have a problem with the `listings` and the `mdframed` package together. The following code compiles with errors, but the only info I managed to get about it is that it was fatal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\newmdenv[linecolor=red,frametitle=Infobox]{infoboxmd}
\makeatletter
\def\@noargument{noargument}
\newenvironment{infobox}[1][noargument]
  {\def\@opt@arg{#1}% Caption optional argument
   \infoboxmd}
  {\endinfoboxmd\par\nobreak%
   \ifx\@opt@arg\@noargument\else\centering\@opt@arg\par\fi}%
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{codetext}[1]{
Something.
#1
\infobox[#1]
Some text.
}{
Some text.
\endinfobox
Something.
}
%\BeforeBeginEnvironment{codetext}{\begin{infobox}[myonlycaption]}
%\AfterEndEnvironment{codetext}{\end{infobox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{codetext}{caption}
Some code.
\end{codetext}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

If I use the (commented out) `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` command instead of `\infobox` it works, but I can't specify the parameter that way.

Associated thread: [mdframed captioning thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135483/captioning-an-mdframed-box-without-making-unbreakable)

Comment: What happens is that LaTeX doesn't exit from the “verbatim” mode initiated with `\begin{codetext}`, so with a non-interactive compilation TeX exits. With an interactive run (from the command line) the input prompt appears, but of course no command can be recognized and forcing exit is the only escape.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Is it somehow my mistake, is it a bug, or is it an undocumented feature?

Comment: A bad interaction with the commands you're using. I didn't find the culprit.

Comment: @egreg: The culprit isn't related to `mdframed` (I guess). I tried the following modified MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{codetext}[1]{
\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}
}{%
\end{lrbox}%
\fbox{\usebox\@tempboxa}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{codetext}{caption}
Some code.
\end{codetext}
\end{document}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel interestingly it works with `mdframed`'s base environment but not with an environment newly defined with `\newmdenv`...

Comment: @cgnieder: Odd. :-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It works when I slightly change the definition of `\newmdenv`: `\renewcommand\newmdenv[2][]{\newenvironment{#2}\mdfsetup{#1}\mdframed}{\endmdframed}}`

Comment: I like this. However, this isn't even correct syntactically: you missed an opening curly bracket after `\newenvironment{#2}`. :)
To enable copy/paste of your code:
`\renewcommand\newmdenv[2][]{\newenvironment{#2}{\mdfsetup{#1}\mdframed}{\endmdfr‌​amed}}`

Comment: masu: a copy/paste & edit error from my editor to the comment but I figured @Marco would understand :)

Comment: Marco would, but there are newbies around, like me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what's going wrong but I have a working alternative: instead of defining a new `mdframed` environment define a new `mdframed` style and use it with `mdframed`'s base environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}

\mdfdefinestyle{infoboxmd}{linecolor=red,frametitle=Infobox}

\makeatletter
\def\@noargument{noargument}
\newenvironment{infobox}[1][noargument]
  {\def\@opt@arg{#1}% Caption optional argument
   \mdframed[style=infoboxmd]}
  {\endmdframed\par\nobreak%
   \ifx\@opt@arg\@noargument\else\centering\@opt@arg\par\fi}%
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{codetext}[1]{%
  Something.
  #1
  \infobox[#1]
  Some text.
}{%
  Some text.
  \endinfobox
  Something.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codetext}{caption}
Some code.
\end{codetext}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just accepted your answer. I'm still eager to know what was the problem with the original, but this solution is working.

Comment: @masu I have the doubt that `listings` environments do something to `\end`... I haven't really checked, though