# Disable or heavily penalise pagebreaking at a specified place

Tags: captions, page-breaking

Is there a way in `LaTeX` to disable (or heavily penalise) pagebreaking at a specified place?

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % demonstration use only

\begin{document}

May break before this.
May break before this.
May break before this.
May break before this.
May break before this.
Don't break before this\\
or before this.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this specific to using `listings` and having content immediately after it?

Comment: It is for me, for now. You supplied an almost perfect [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135483/captioning-an-mdframed-box-without-making-unbreakable) for one of my questions for which this is an extension. But I don't know any general answers in the topic, so I formulated the question to gain as much knowledge as possible. :)

Comment: I'll have to look into this...

Comment: The main problem is that `\end{lstlisting}` adds a feasible break point and undo this effect requires going deep in the innards of the package. On the other hand, a break before "or before this" can be avoided with the standard ``\\*``.

Comment: I knew I could pose a really good question I try hard enough. 2 accepted answers so far for my 6 questions. :( Thank you @Werner for the effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `needspace` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\needspace{4\baselineskip} % to avoid 3 orphan lines.
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Or you can increase the `\clubpenalty` for {some part}, but  like `\nopagebreak[n]` this is a request, not a demand.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
{\clubpenalty 10000  % to avoid 1 orphan line 
\lipsum[5]}
\end{document}
```

Or simply a `\vbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\vbox{\lipsum[5]}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\nopagebreak[priority]` where *priority* is a integer from 0 to 4. In your example it could be

```
...
\nopagebreak[4]
Don't break before this
...
```

to avoid a pagebreak at all.

Comment: Hmm... it does not work for me.