# Avoid page break after last line in lstlisting

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I have a listing as follows:

```
\lstdefinestyle{yamlCode} {
    numbers=left,
    language=Yaml,
    backgroundcolor={\color{lightgray!40}},
    breaklines=true,
    frame=single,
    columns=fixed
}

[...]

\begin{lstlisting}[style=yamlCode,label=YamlList,
caption=List of Maps in YAML.]
persons:
  - name:  Peter
    email: peter@example.org
  - name:  Sally
    email: sally@example.org
\end{lstlisting}
```

Now that listing might break *after* the last line of code, as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: page break]

How can I prevent the page break after the last line? At least one line should be moved to the next page as well. Just to be clear: I do want it to break pages, however, not after the *last* line. How can I achieve that?

PS: Are the white lines between the code lines rendering artefacts or real? When I open the PDF in Adobe Reader and zoom in, I can still see them. Not very nice.

Comment: use the optional argument `float`.

Comment: @Herbert I tried several variations with float including `float`, `float=h`, `th`, `tbh`. But none of these breaks the listing at the page end. It will either be completely on the first or on the second page. Should using `float` page-break the listing?

Comment: with `begin{lstlisting}[float,...]` it is handled like a floatimng object and cannot have a pagebreak inside. It is moved to the other page. The only thing you can do if you want it on the same page is `\enlagethispage{\normalbaselineskip}` before the listing.

Comment: @Herbert Yes the floating does what you say, but I'd rather have a proper page break. Using `enlargethispage` does not seem like a viable solution as I would have to add that to every single listing were such ugly page breaks occur. If there is no other solution to that problem, I will use `float=h` for now.

Comment: You may find related info in the comments of [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135807/disable-or-heavily-penalise-pagebreaking-at-a-specified-place)

Comment: @masu Thanks, I tried the proposed solutions but none of them made a difference. Did anything work for you?

Comment: Not yet. The only really useful info right now is the comment of egreg. I hope this will change.