# How to undo the feasible breakpoints of `lstlisting`?

Tags: listings, page-breaking

Is there a way to prohibit pagebreaking at the beginning/end of an `lstlisting` environment?

I'm trying to keep together the following two pairs of lines:

- the first line of `lstlisting` and the line before that
- the last line of `lstlisting` and the line after that

But pagebreaking should be available (so using `minipage` is not a solution) - there are code snippets more than one page long.

[As far as I know](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135807/disable-or-heavily-penalise-pagebreaking-at-a-specified-place#comment307043_135807) `\end{lstlisting}` implicitly adds a feasible breakpoint so it has to be undone to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Keep the first two together}

\vspace{22\baselineskip}

\noindent Line Before
\begin{lstlisting}
First line
Middle lines
Middle lines
Middle lines
Last line
\end{lstlisting}
Line After

\newpage

\textbf{Keep the last two together}

\vspace{17\baselineskip}

\noindent Line Before
\begin{lstlisting}
First line
Middle lines
Middle lines
Middle lines
Last line
\end{lstlisting}
Line After

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you add a link to the previous question of yours where this issue arose (I read it recently, there was a comment of `egreg` about this "feasible breakpoint").

Comment: @jfbu: I intented to do that but forgot it somehow. [Here it is](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135807/disable-or-heavily-penalise-pagebreaking-at-a-specified-place#comment307043_135807), but I don't think it will help much, most of the content is in the last sentence of my actual question.

Comment: Using `\vbox` as in Fran's answer in the mentioned post doesn't work?

Comment: @karlkoeller no, it doesn't do the things mentioned above.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159874/penalize-page-breaks-in-lstlistings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unanswered question with my ol' `listings`. How nice.

Replace the incumbent `vspace` - depending how you look at it - on **listings.sty** with `abovedisplayskip` and `belowdisplayskip` respectively.

To sum it up, we are going to line 1723:

```
 \else
 \lst@ifdisplaystyle
    \lst@EveryDisplay
    \par\penalty-50\relax
    \vspace\lst@aboveskip
```

And modify it to:

```
\else
\lst@ifdisplaystyle
\lst@EveryDisplay
\par\penalty-50\relax
\lst@belowskip\lst@aboveskip
```

Then to line 1776 regardless of its historical context:

```
 \else
         \lst@ifdisplaystyle
             \par\penalty-50\vspace\lst@belowskip
```

and modify it as well:

```
 \else
         \lst@ifdisplaystyle
             \par\penalty-50\lst@aboveskip\lst@belowskip
```

Your sample:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
 \usepackage{listings}

 \begin{document}

 \textbf{Keep the first two together}

 \vspace{15\baselineskip}

 \noindent Line Before
 \begin{lstlisting}
 First line
 Middle lines
 Middle lines
 Middle lines
 Last line
 \end{lstlisting}
 Line After

 \newpage

 \textbf{Keep the last two together}

 \vspace{15\baselineskip}

 \noindent Line Before
 \begin{lstlisting}
 First line
 Middle lines
 Middle lines
 Middle lines
 Last line
 \end{lstlisting}
 Line After

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does not really matter now for me as I have not used LaTeX for about 3 years, but thanks anyway. :D

Comment: @masu the crystal ball whispered you are using LuaTeX... is the ball correct?

Comment: It could be. But it is not. :D

As I finished the PhD studies but did not go any further in the academic life I don't really do anything in LaTeX now... I mostly use python (and Office for documents). A bit of blasphemy here, I know. :D

Comment: @masu That's unheard of. :) But it frees you from the constraints of TeX ubiquities. On the other hand, a great many who also completed their thesis without it, have said that they simply lacked the knowledge with TeX. So they did not pursue it any further. Had they been endowed with your skills to do so, they would have probably press on it.