# Add vertical space only if there is no pagebreak

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I'd like to define a new `listings` environment where the listing has an `\hrule` before and after the listing itself. In order to do this I've defined this environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{haskell}[1][]
    {
        \vspace{0.4cm}
        \mathligsoff
        \hrule
        \lstset{language=haskell, basicstyle=\small, #1}
    }{
        \hrule
        \mathligson
        \vspace{0.4cm}
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, when a listing ends up at the bottom of a page, the closing `\hrule` moves to the next page:

[image: image showing the extra rule at the start of the new page]

As you can see the highlighted rule ended up at the start of the new page, which is just ugly.

How can I avoid to produce a pagebreak between the listing and the rule at the end? I have already tried to add a `\nopagebreak` before `\hrule` but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140314/how-to-undo-the-feasible-breakpoints-of-lstlisting

Comment: You may want to use `tcolorbox` to draw the surrounding "box". The general consensus is that `tcolorbox` handles that kind of situation better than the native mechanism implemented in `listings`.

Answer (score 1):

Like indicated [in the comments by Jubobs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203393/add-vertical-space-only-if-there-is-no-pagebreak#comment474801_203393) I'd use [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) for this. The following code mimicks the layout outlined in the question but with `tcolorbox` a lot fancier layouts easily are possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,listings}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,xparse}
\tcbset{listing engine=listings}

\NewTCBListing{haskell}{O{}}{%
  % colors:
  colback = white , colframe = black , coltitle = black ,
  % rules:
  boxrule = 0pt , toprule = 1pt , bottomrule = 1pt , arc = 0pt ,
  % spacing:
  boxsep = 0pt , left = 0pt , right = 0pt ,
  % listing options:
  listing options = {
    language = haskell ,
    basicstyle = \small ,
    gobble = 2 ,%
    #1%
  } ,
  listing only
}

\begin{document}

\begin{haskell}
  sums = zipWith (\x y -> x + y) numbers1 numbers2
  products = zipWith (\x y -> x * y) numbers1 numbers2
  pairs = zipWith (\x y -> (x, y)) numbers1 numbers2
\end{haskell}

\end{document}
```

Unless you specify the `breakable` option of `tcolorbox` (needs the `breakable` library) the complete listing will stay on one page.

[image]